# Make monodevelop use multiple cpu cores

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop, cpu-cores

I run a c# .exe code on an ubuntu server using monodevelop and I have not admin access. Server has a 48 core cpu but my process only use one core! How can I make monodevelop use multiple cpu cores?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads in your application? What kind of application (GTK#, console, etc)? Where is the code you need to run on multiple cores?

Comment: @RonBeyer: It's a console application and of course I used multiple threads!
My code runs fine on windows and use all cores of cpu!

Comment: Can you show us *how* you used the threads?

Comment: @RonBeyer
Parallel.For(0, L1, parallelOption, j =>
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < sparseFeatureSize; i++)
              {
                  var entry = sparse.GetEntry(i);

                  neuHidden[j].netIn += entry.Value * mat_input2hidden[j][entry.Key].wInputInputGate;
              }
          });